# How can I get a file's "current" size in Python?

Tags: python, file, copy, size

I would like to write a program in Python, that copies files to a flash drive after they have been downloaded.

So my concept is, that if I download a 5 GB file, the program waits until the file's size reaches 5 GB (finished downloading) and after that it copies.

To get file size I use:

```
os.path.getsize()
```

Which always returns 5 GB, even when the download has just begun, because 5 GB is already written in the properties of the file before it has finished downloading, and there is another data "disk storage/size" which says the current size of the file (other than 5 GB while downloading).

The problem is, that I was unsuccessful finding a command, that returns me the "current" size.

Can you help me in that? Or can you suggest me another way to approach this whole process of copying these files?

Comment: Have you looked at the modified timestamp?